# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined userClicked @ funcs.gs:8

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have made an web app using google script connected to spreadsheet.

all was running well till i tried to put a functionality of sending email notification when user submits a form information

see error code when run log of user clicked function-
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined userClicked   @funcs.gs:8

function-js page is below

```
  'function userClicked(userInfo) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url1);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("SNAGS");
  ws.appendRow([userInfo.fn, 
                userInfo.contact,
                userInfo.email,
                userInfo.house,
                userInfo.snag, 
                userInfo.query,
                new Date()]);
```

```js
 <script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
                              {

                                 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
                                 document.getElementById("house").addEventListener("input",getInfo);

                                 var selectBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('select');
                                  M.FormSelect.init(selectBoxes);
                      
                                  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateHouse).getHouse();

                              }
                           ); 



        function populateHouse(hous)
                              {
                                 var autocomplete = document.getElementById('house');
                                 var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(autocomplete, { data: hous });
                              }
  

        function doStuff()                        
                          
                         {
                           var isValid = document.getElementById("fn").checkValidity();

                           if(!isValid)
                                       {
                                         M.toast({html: 'Name Required!'});
                                       }
                              else
                                       {
                                          addRecord();
                                        }
                         }

      
      function addRecord ()
                          {
                              var userInfo = {};
     
                                      userInfo.fn = document.getElementById("fn").value;
                                      userInfo.contact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
                                      userInfo.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                                      userInfo.house = document.getElementById("house").value;
                                      userInfo.snag = document.getElementById("snag").value;
                                      userInfo.query = document.getElementById("query").value;


                                    google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
       
                                    document.getElementById("fn").value ="";
                                    document.getElementById("contact").value ="";
                     document.getElementById("email").value ="";
                                    document.getElementById("house").value ="";
                                    document.getElementById("snag").value ="";
                                    document.getElementById("query").value ="";

                                    M.updateTextFields();


                                  var myApp = document.getElementById("snag");
                                   myApp.selectedIindex = 0;
                                  M.FormSelect.init(myApp);

                          }

       function getInfo ()
                          {

                             var HouseInfo = document.getElementById("house").value;
                            
                             if(HouseInfo.length === 3)
                                {
                                  google.script.run.withSucceshandler(updateInfo).getData(HouseInfo);

                                }
                          }


      function updateInfo (infos)
                            {
                              document.getElementById("info").value = infos;
                              M.updateTextFields();
                           }
                          

 </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_self">

         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>  
  </head>
  
  <body>

      <div class="container">

               <h3>TPM Maintance |Ticketing System</h3>
               <br>

           <div class="row">
     
                     <div class="input-field col s4">
                       <input placeholder="Your Full Names" id="fn" type="text" class="validate" required >
                       <label for="fn">Your Name:</label>
                     </div>

                     <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input id="contact" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="contact"> Your Phone number:</label>
                     </div>  


                      <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate" required>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                     </div>       
               
          </div>
            
      
            
            
      <div class="row">
                    
                   

                     <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">home</i>
                        <input type="text" id="house" class="autocomplete" required>
                        <label for="house">Location Area/ House Unit# </label>
                     </div>

                       <div class="input-field col s4">
                      <select id="snag" required>
                        <option disabled selected> Snag Category</option>
                            <?!= list; ?>
                      </select>
                      <label>Snag Type</label>
                     </div>   

                      <div class="input-field col s4">
                        <input disabled id="info" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="info">Unit_Info</label>
                     </div>

                       
              </div>
           


              <div class="row">          
              
                          <div class="input-field col s12">
                             <textarea id="query" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
                             <label for="query">Query Desc:</label>
                          </div> 

              </div>
       
                    
          <div class="row">
   
             <button id="btn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light deep-orange darken-2" type="submit" name="action">Send Ticket!
             <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
             </button>
             
          </div>
           
      
    </div>

     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script> 
            
    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>
  </body>



</html>
//html part
```

please see more code from my work thanks. please excuse me im abit a newbie

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the meantime, check how your call to ````userClicked```` changed when you put the new functionality.

Comment: I would say that the parameter userInfo was either not passed or undefined.  Sometime's the user from Class Session does not get passed due to a complicated set of security restrictions and so you should probably be checking to insure that the parameter is defined before using it.

Comment: Hi @CarlosM . thanks for your reply I have added more info for clarity. excuse me still a newbie trying to grasp,, i was following this youtube tutorial while working this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gi_xlZ5K9rs) btw

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the steps from the tutorial video you have tried to run `userClicked()` function to authorize the Gmail API's. Since Apps Script is thinking that it's a standalone function, `userInfo` is considered undefined. This is expected behavior.

**Excerpt from video:**

[image]